# Django get ContentType in a template

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-contenttypes

I have a page with a lot of objects with different content types. I need to have an ability to  rate this objects. Here is a class for it:

```
class Score(models.Model):
    user            = models.ForeignKey(User)

    content_type    = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id       = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    for_object      = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

    like            = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created_at      = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True)

    comment         = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

    objects = ChainerManager(ScoreQuerySet)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'Score for (%s, #%s) from user %s at %s' %\
            (self.content_type, self.object_id, self.user.get_full_name(), self.created_at)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('user', 'content_type', 'object_id'),)
```

And my template should look like:

```
...
{% for random_object in random_object_queryset %}
<a href={% url like_object random_object.<content_type> random_object.id %}>{{ random_object.name }}</a>
<a href={% url dislike_object random_object.<content_type> random_object.id %}>{{ random_object.name }}</a>
{% endfor %}
...
```

I can make template tag to get it, or get a classname, using i.e. this snippet: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/294/
I can rewrite this snuppet to get the content_type_id for object, but i'm afraid a little about big amount of CT lookups in DB.

But is there some embedded method to get object's CT in a template?

**The view code:**

```
def rate_object(request, classname, object_id, like=True):
    user = request.user
    Klass = ContentType.objects.get(model=classname).model_class()
    obj = get_object_or_404(Klass, user=user, pk=object_id)

    try:
        score = Score.objects.for_object(user, obj)
        score.like = like
        score.save()
    except Score.DoesNotExist:
        score = Score.objects.like(user, obj) if like else Score.objects.dislike(user, obj)

    return HttpResponse(obj)
```

Comment: Just for information: You shouldn't add that much spaces after your variables. It's not PEP8 ( http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#whitespace-in-expressions-and-statements )

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To build on @Colleen 's answer, I ended up using a template filter like so:

```
from django import template
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def content_type(obj):
    if not obj:
        return False
    return ContentType.objects.get_for_model(obj)
```

And used it in a template like so:

```
{% load helpers %}
{% with instance|content_type as ctype %}
    <input type="hidden" name="content_type" value="{{ ctype.pk }}">
{% endwith %}
```

Comment: for further discussion and forking, [see this snippet](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/3015/)

Comment: This ``{% with instance|content_type as ctype %}`` syntax, is it documented and supported? Does ``{% with a=b|c %}`` also work? What about ``{% with a=b|c d=e|f %}``? I can't find it in the documentation.

Comment: `with` is a built-in template tag (as opposed to the custom filter above), [here it is in Django's official docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/templates/builtins/#with)

Comment: I know. What I can't find out is whether you can use filters in ``with``. Apparently you have tried it and it works, but I was wondering whether it is documented and supported behaviour.

Comment: Good point, it seems it is not explicitly stated anywhere. Though it is implied in at least a couple of places. For instance [in the introduction to tags/filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#tags) check out the part about `if` variables able to use a filter, or in the [`dictsort` filter examples](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#dictsort).

Answer (score 4):

I prefer doing this with [assignment tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/custom-template-tags/#assignment-tags) (new in Django 1.4):

```
@register.assignment_tag
def content_type(obj):
    if not obj:
        return False
    return ContentType.objects.get_for_model(obj)
```

and used as

```
{% content_type object as object_ct %}
```

Answer (score 2):

I also had a situation where I needed the content type in the template and the only way I found I could get it was through a custom template tag.

In your situation, though, since you're storing content_type explicitly as a foreign key, I wouldn't worry about it. Worst case you can use `prefetch_related()` when you get your score objects in the view. I don't know if Django is smart enough to stop at the field if you ask for a foreignkey.id, is the only thing.